# Validating an unix cURL command

Tags: php, unix, curl

I am relatively new to cURL. 
I have a cURL command to upload a csv to an API endpoint. 
Here is the cURL,

```
curl 'https://api.myweb.tld/something/upload' \
­-X POST \
­-H 'Authorization: Basic SomeRandomTokenIHaveReceived' \
­-H 'Content­Type: multipart/form­data' \
­-F 'csv=@./the_file.csv' \
­-F 'encoding=windows­1252' \
­-F 'fieldSeparator=,' \
­­-- compressed | json_pp > response.json
```

what it does is simply passing the value inside the csv to the API endpoint. and receive the response in the response.json to know whether or not the operation succeeded.

I run it on OSX terminal and get this response in the response.json file

```
{
   "type" : "APIException",
   "message" : "Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed methods are: POST,OPTIONS.",
   "identifier" : 70004,
   "statusCode" : 405
}
```

and I also get some warnings in the terminal like below :

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­X
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­H
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­H
curl: (3) Port number ended with ' '
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­F
curl: (7) Failed to connect to  port 80: Connection refused
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­F
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: encoding=windows­1252
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­F
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: fieldSeparator=,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ­­compressed
```

can anyone point out what is wrong with it? 
do I need something else to execute this? 
how does it work if I would like to run this in PHP? 
I am just not that familiar with cURL and the nature of it, would be glad if someone can give me some hints.

Thanks all!

Comment: options should be prefixed with `-`

Comment: Thanks, I edited my description, the "-" was not copied properly. 
what about the whole structure? is that fine?

Comment: In PHP, that's not the syntax for cURL.  See the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Seems fine. For something complex it's usually easier to start with postman and then convert to curl https://blog.postman.com/curl-and-postman-work-wonderfully-together/

Comment: @Oleg thanks to your comment, I can validate the request via postman and export it as php curl with Postman Documentation builder. Should have known this earlier! Thanks Oleg! send you a virtual !